# UWP set background from dark/light dictionary

Tags: uwp, contentdialog

```
 var solcolor = (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["PopUpsBackground"];
 this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(solcolor.Color);
```

I set the Background of ContentDialogs programmatically but it gets the requested theme color from an application, but I need to get the color that I set. I find this:

```
   dialog.RequestedTheme = (Window.Current.Content as FrameworkElement).RequestedTheme;
```

But now I need to get color from the dictionary I need( dark or light)
I also find this:

```
Background="{Binding Source={ThemeResource PopUpsBackground}}"
```

but it does not work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> UWP set background from dark/light dictionary

You need set `ThemeDictionaries` in the `Application.Resources` like following. And custom ContentDialog's style edit the default Background property as your custom value. For more detail please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-theme-resources).

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DialogColor" Color="Red" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DialogColor" Color="SeaGreen" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>


    <Style TargetType="ContentDialog">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ContentDialogForeground}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource DialogColor}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ContentDialogBorderBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" /> 
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Please note, for making ContentDialog new style effect, you need restart your app after change current theme.